# Unable to post data using ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I am low **mvc6** and **c#** skills, I am trying to post, when I sumbit it's doing nothing.

It wont take me to the controller, just stays on the page.

I have more pages, I dont know where is the problem, I will add the rest if need

Here my **Controller**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers.Web
{
  public class AppController : Controller
  {
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

here my Contact:

```
@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.ContactViewModel

@{ 
ViewBag.Title = "Contact Page";
}

@section scripts{
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-        unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
 }
 <h2>Contact Me</h2>

  <form method="post">

    <span asp-validtaion-summary="ModelOnly"></span>

    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
   <input asp-for="Name"/>
   <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>

   <label asp-for="Email"></label>
   <input  type="email" asp-for="Email"/>
   <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>

  <label asp-for="Message"></label>
   <textarea cols="40" rows="4" asp-for="Message"></textarea>
   <span asp-validation-for="Message"></span>

   <div>
   <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
   </div>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to tell the "form" what to do, when the user submits it. For MVC6 you can use this tag helper:

```
<form asp-controller="App" asp-action="Contact">
    ...
</form>
```

This will output something like

```
<form action="/App/Contact" method="post">
```

And now the Browser knows the action url and where to send to data.